# Issue With codeSubDirectories

Tags: c#, asp.net, runtime-error, app-code

This is a lengthy one - please bear..!

I have a web-site that currently uses a monolith "app_code" dll file - and am looking at breaking the dll into pieces for better maintenance.

I'm using the  section in web.config to split-up my app_code into multiple, folder-wise dll files. The section looks like this:

```
<codeSubDirectories>
  <add directoryName="CodeSubDir1"/>
  <add directoryName="CodeSubDir2"/>
  ...
</codeSubDirectories>
```

I've created separate sub-folders for each of the `.cs` files within the "app_code" folder except for a handful of .cs files that refer each other - so needed to be placed together in the same sub-folder. The .cs files are moved to their corresponding sub-folder.
After these changes, there is no .cs file that is directly under the "app_code" folder. I've set the order of the elements within *codeSubDirectories* such that all other references are taken care of.

The site builds and publishes successfully in my dev. environment. The "Allow this precompiled site to be updatable" and "Used fixed naming and single page assemblies" check-boxes are checked while publishing. No `app_code.dll` and `app_code.compiled` files are created during the publish as there are no .cs files directly under the "app_code" folder. Every sub-folder under app_code is published as `app_subcode_sub_folder_name.dll` and `app_subcode_sub_folder_name.compiled`.

Both the site and its published version work fine as well in my dev. environment.

After I update the published files to my staging setup [`.NET 3.5/IIS 6/Win 2003]`, I'm getting these two errors [on two separate URLs]:

**Error on URL-1:**
Could not load file or assembly 'App_Code, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'App_Code, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Source File: xxx\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\xxx\xxx\xxx\App_Web_xxx.8.cs    Line: 0

**Error on URL-2:**
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

My staging-update process is: I copy the `"app_subcode_xxx.dll"` and `"app_subcode_xxx.compiled"` files to the "bin" folder and delete the existing "app_code.dll" and "app_code.compiled" files. I add the *codeSubDirectories* section to the web.config on staging.

I've searched the `GAC`, Code and Registry for any reference to the assembly "app_code" with no luck. What am I missing out? Are there any additional steps needed to make this work on my staging site? Do I need to copy ALL other published DLLs as well from dev. to staging?

Comment: Personally I don't use the `codeSubDirectories` node as everything in the `App_Code` folder is compiled anyway. When I create a subdirectory in the `App_Code` folder I use the folders name as a namespace for the files within the folder; so each class in the subfolder has `namespace MySubFolderName` - I find this is an easier way to keep things tidy and finding the `.cs` file is much easier when using the intellisense. I know this doesn't help you with your current error, though it might give you another, less-bothersome, way to layout your code.

Answer (score 0):

Copy all the dlls and compiled files from the publish folder to the staging environment. Chances are other dlls and compiled files are still referencing the appcode.